# Regex Multiple Matches PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to get all numbers from a string, having `-` or `_` before the number and optional `-` `_` `space` or the end of string at the end of the number.

So, my regex looks like this:

```
[-_][\d]+[-_ $]?
```

My problem is, I don't match numbers right after each other. From a "foo-5234_2123_54-13-20" string, I only get `5234`, `54` and `20`.

What I tried is the following regexes: `(?:[-_])[\d]+(?:[-_ $])?` and `[-_]([\d]+)[-_ $]?` that obviously didn't work. I'm looking for hours now and I know it can't be that hard so I hope someone can help me here.

If that makes any difference, I'm using PHP `preg_match_all`.

Comment: Perhaps, you are looking for `(?<=[-_])\d+(?=[-_ ]|$)`? https://regex101.com/r/kZ0tV2/2. For a more generic approach, vks suggestion is correct. Please outline your requirements in the question.

Comment: \b\d+\b only matched 2 numbers. But stribizhev answer worked thank you a lot.

Comment: I added an answer and +1. It is always pleasure to help someone who tries hard.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use [look-arounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<=[-_])\d+(?=[-_ ]|$)
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kZ0tV2/2)

Fortunately, PHP supports at least fixed-width look-behinds, and we can use it here.